# Pyspark: can slice list, but can't index

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pyspark, rdd

This in pyspark where r_parsed is an RDD,

```
 r_parsed = r_parsed.map(lambda x: ([k for k in x.keys()][:3]))
 x = r_parsed.collect()[666]
 print(x)

 ['is_quote_status', 'place', 'in_reply_to_user_id']
```

But then..

```
r_parsed = r_parsed.map(lambda x: ([k for k in x.keys()][1]))
x = r_parsed.collect()[666]
```

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 1 in stage 120.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   1.0 in stage 120.0 (TID 241, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File
>   "/home/filipe/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 229, in main
>       process()   File "/home/filipe/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py",
>   line 224, in process
>       serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)   File
>   "/home/filipe/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py",
>   line 372, in dump_stream
>       vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))   File "", line 5, in  IndexError:
>   list index out of range

What sorcery is this? Why can I map a list slice, but not a list index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the slicing syntax can handle the case where the length of the list is less than the slice length.

For example:

```
my_list = [1]
print(my_list[:3])
#[1]
```

However, indexing is not as forgiving:

```
print(my_list[1])
IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f6bea31a1a9e> in <module>()
----> 1 print(my_list[1])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Somewhere in your `rdd`, you have a row where the length of the keys is less than 2.

You may want to first filter:

```
r_parsed = r_parsed.filter(lambda x: len(x.keys()) > 1).map(lambda x: x.keys()[1])
```

Or build the logic into your map function:

```
r_parsed = r_parsed.map(lambda x: x.keys()[1] if len(x.keys()) > 1 else None)
```